# I decided to embed bootstrap template. to laravel 5.5

Tags: html, css, laravel-5

The code is here:

[image: The code is here]

But i couldn't link with the css.

I tried using

```
{{asset('public/added')}}
```

All the templates css,vendor,js are kept in the public/added folder.

The result in the browser is here:

[image: The result in the browser is here]

Comment: Kindly paste your code.. Also please use the Chrome>view page source or inpect to view the elements which are loaded for the particular page

Comment: Try putting whole url in the asset and not just `public/added`

Comment: use {{asset('added/css/your-style.css'}} -- You dont have to add public while you asset since it will fetch the data from the folder..

Answer (score 0):

By Default the asset helper will look under the public directory

From looking inthe picture your project structure is

```
public > added > css > css-files.css
```

For this you could use

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('added/css/css-files.css')}}">
```

*You can omit the public since laravel asset helper will pick it for you*

Alternatively you could use **{{url}}** helper or you could paste the whole url

Hope this would help you,

Comment: I tried keeping whole url in the asset but it still didn't work .

Comment: can you please use the right click on chrome and click view full page source and let us know what url it is displaying

Comment: Could you please show us your latest edit as per your old comment

Comment: <link href="{{asset('added/vendor/bootstrap-4.1/bootstrap.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" media="all">

Comment: great, can you please right click on the page(img 2) > view page source > and share us the screenshot of the head section  shared before

Comment: Also use > f12 > in console tab - are you getting any error ?

Comment: i didn't get any error there.   I couldn't send the image. There is no image upload section in comment

Comment: Thank you so much for your help :)  .....It worked with the other template.